# Create Rails scope for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models:

DeliverySlot has_many :orders 
Order belongs_to :delivery_slot

Delivery Slots have a limit of how many orders they can hold. I want to create a scope to give all the available delivery slots. An available delivery slot is one that hasn't reached it's limit of associated orders.

My attempt looks like:

```
scope :available, where("limit > ?", order.count).joins(:orders)
```

order.count is pseudocode above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this like you have setup you would need to use `orders.count` instead of `order.count` because you're referring to the association. This would prompt ActiveRecord to assemble a query that looks something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE delivery_slot_id = 1`.

Rails is actually smart enough to then use that as a subquery in your `where` condition when you pass it appropriately, a la `where('limit > ', orders.count)`. But as you might see, this won't work if it's precompiled because the query uses an explicit ID in the condition.

What you need instead is to count orders with an ambiguous condition, then use it as a subquery: `where('limit > ?', Order.where(delivery_slot_id: 'delivery_slots.id').count)`. If you tried to run the query for the order count on its own it would fail on `delivery_slots`, but because it's in the subquery here you should be smooth sailing.

I'd like to propose another way of doing this altogether though, using a counter cache:

```
class AddCounterCacheToDeliverySlots < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class DeliverySlot < ActiveRecord::Base; end
  def change
    add_column :delivery_slots, :orders_count, :integer, default: 0
    add_index :delivery_slots, [:orders_count, :limit]

    DeliverySlot.reset_column_information
    DeliverySlot.find_each do |delivery_slot|
      DeliverySlot.update_counters delivery_slot.id, orders_count: delivery_slot.orders.count
    end
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :delivery_slot, counter_cache: true
end

class DeliverySlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many orders
  scope :available, where('orders_count < limit')
end
```

Rails will automatically increment and decrement the `orders_count` column for each `DeliverySlot`, and because it's indexed, it's ridiculously fast to query.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't know about counter caches. I've implemented it like that now.

Comment: @MarkRobinson Hey, I saw your suggested edit and I want to clarify that the `class DeliverySlot < ActiveRecord::Base; end` line is no mistake. It's there to remove coupling between this exact version of your model and this migration that would make it much more brittle.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :available, lambda { 
  |delivery_slot| joins(:orders).
         where("limit > ?", order.count) 
}
```

try this

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work - my understanding of the lambda function is it lets you pass in a variable that changes each time you call it. Nothing changes each time in what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmm ya... why are you passing `delivery_slot` as a parameter to the lambda block, but never using it?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to do it in SQL. If anyone knows of a more ruby way without creating loads of database queries please jump in.

```
scope :available, joins('LEFT JOIN orders 
    ON orders.delivery_slot_id = delivery_slots.id')
    .where("delivery_slots.limit > ( 
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.delivery_slot_id = delivery_slots.id )
    ")
```